# How do i add all the lines to the SetupText(new string[] {?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the code:

```
readableRss = RssReader.covertRss("http://rotter.net/rss/rotternews.xml");
            string[] lines = Regex.Split(readableRss, "\r\n");
            this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed = new string[5];
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                counter += 1;
                if (counter <= 5)
                {
                    lines[i] = "hi";
                    SetupText(new string[] { lines[0],lines[1] });
                }
                else
                {
                    counter = 0;
                }

            }
            this.newsFeed1.TextColor = new Color[5];
            SetupColors(new Color[] { Color.Blue, Color.Lime, Color.Maroon, Color.FromArgb(255, 71, 71, 255), Color.BurlyWood });
            this.newsFeed1.Spacing = this.newsFeed1.Height;
            this.newsFeed1.SetTexts();
            this.newsFeed1.startFeed();
```

In the variables lines i have 151 lines. Each line contain a string for example:

"hello everyone the weather today is..."

And i have this line:

```
SetupText(new string[] { lines[0],lines[1] });
```

Im looping using FOR over the lines and add each line to the SetupText.
But how can i add all the lines using the loop and not add them one by one like i did ?
I will not write now lines[0] lines[1].....lines[151]

If im changing it to this:

```
lines[i] = "hi";
SetupText(new string[] { lines[i] });
```

Then i see only "hi" once.
But i dont see all the other lines since lines[i] is only one place in SetupText

If im doing:

```
lines[i] = "hi";
SetupText(new string[] { lines[i],lines[i] });
```

I will see the "hi" twice.
If i remove the line:

```
lines[i] = "hi";
```

I dont see anything.
I need that SetupText will contain all the lines from the variables lines.

EDIT:

This is form1 code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace RssNews
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string readableRss;
        string t = "";
        int counter;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }




        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            readableRss = RssReader.covertRss("http://rotter.net/rss/rotternews.xml");
            string[] lines = Regex.Split(readableRss, "\r\n");
            this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed = new string[5];
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                counter += 1;
                if (counter <= 5)
                {
                    lines[i] = "hi";
                    SetupText(new string[] { lines[i],lines[i] });
                }
                else
                {
                    counter = 0;
                }

            }
            this.newsFeed1.TextColor = new Color[5];
            SetupColors(new Color[] { Color.Blue, Color.Lime, Color.Maroon, Color.FromArgb(255, 71, 71, 255), Color.BurlyWood });
            this.newsFeed1.Spacing = this.newsFeed1.Height;
            this.newsFeed1.SetTexts();
            this.newsFeed1.startFeed();
        }

        private void SetupColors(Color[] colors)
        {
              if (this.newsFeed1.TextColor.Length > 0 && colors.Length > 0)
                   this.newsFeed1.TextColor[0] = colors[0];
               if (this.newsFeed1.TextColor.Length > 1 && colors.Length > 1)
                   this.newsFeed1.TextColor[1] = colors[1];
               if (this.newsFeed1.TextColor.Length > 2 && colors.Length > 2)
                   this.newsFeed1.TextColor[2] = colors[2];
               if (this.newsFeed1.TextColor.Length > 3 && colors.Length > 3)
                   this.newsFeed1.TextColor[3] = colors[3];
               if (this.newsFeed1.TextColor.Length > 4 && colors.Length > 4)
                   this.newsFeed1.TextColor[4] = colors[4];
        }

        private void SetupText(string[] textToDisplay)
        {
             if (this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed.Length > 0 && textToDisplay.Length > 0)
                  this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed[0] = textToDisplay[0];
              if (this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed.Length > 1 && textToDisplay.Length > 1)
                  this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed[1] = textToDisplay[1];
              if (this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed.Length > 2 && textToDisplay.Length > 2)
                  this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed[2] = textToDisplay[2];
              if (this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed.Length > 3 && textToDisplay.Length > 3)
                  this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed[3] = textToDisplay[3];
              if (this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed.Length > 4 && textToDisplay.Length > 4)
                  this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed[4] = textToDisplay[4];
        }
    }
}
```

And im using NewsFeed UserControl to animate the text inside so it will move from bottom to top.

EDIT**

This is the user control NewsFeed.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;

namespace RssNews
{
    public partial class NewsFeed : UserControl
    {
        SpeechSynthesizer speaker;
        Label[] list = new Label[5];
        int jump = 0;

        public string[] NewsTextFeed { get; set; }
        public Color[] TextColor { get; set; }

        private int _spacing = 10;
        public int Spacing
        {
            get { return _spacing; }
            set { _spacing = value; }
        }

        public NewsFeed()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            speaker = new SpeechSynthesizer();
            Init();
        }

        private void Init()
        {
            // Initialise Position Variables 
            int x = 2;
            int y = this.Height; // just out of view at top. 

            // Assign each label in list the following properties 
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                list[i] = new Label();
                list[i].AutoSize = false;
                list[i].Location = new Point(x, y + (_spacing * i)); // The math is the UserControl size for example 150x150 and then 150/the number of labels for example 150/5=30 so it will be 30 * i \\
                this.Controls.Add(list[i]); // Add control to UserControl 
            }
            startFeed();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Label label in list)
            // Loop through List with for-each 
            {
                // Move label up 'jump' pixels 
                label.Location = new Point(label.Location.X, label.Location.Y - jump);

                // Check to see if out of view. 
                if (label.Location.Y <= -_spacing)
                {
                    //calculate the new Y-Position by summing all heights + the sum of _spacing - 1 time spacing, cause it is now at the ypoint -spacing
                    int newPosY = list.Sum((b) => (b.Height));
                    label.Location = new Point(label.Location.X, newPosY + _spacing * (list.Length - 1));
                }
            }
        }

        public void SetTexts()
        {
            if (list.Length > 4 && NewsTextFeed != null)
            {
                //get the label at this position in the list
                //and assign some text
                if (list[0] != null && this.NewsTextFeed[0] != null && NewsTextFeed.Length > 0)
                    list[0].Text = this.NewsTextFeed[0];
                //  speaker.SpeakAsync(list[0].Text); // this is where we make the text to speech...to add option for it yes or not using the option in form1.
                if (list[1] != null && this.NewsTextFeed[1] != null && NewsTextFeed.Length > 1)
                    list[1].Text = this.NewsTextFeed[1];

                if (list[2] != null && this.NewsTextFeed[2] != null && NewsTextFeed.Length > 2)
                    list[2].Text = this.NewsTextFeed[2];

                if (list[3] != null && this.NewsTextFeed[3] != null && NewsTextFeed.Length > 3)
                    list[3].Text = this.NewsTextFeed[3];

                if (list[4] != null && this.NewsTextFeed[4] != null && NewsTextFeed.Length > 4)
                    list[4].Text = this.NewsTextFeed[4];
            }

            if (list.Length > 4 && TextColor != null)
            {
                if (list[0] != null && TextColor.Length > 0 && !TextColor[0].Equals(Color.Transparent))
                    list[0].ForeColor = TextColor[0];

                if (list[1] != null && TextColor.Length > 1 && !TextColor[1].Equals(Color.Transparent))
                    list[1].ForeColor = TextColor[1];

                if (list[2] != null && TextColor.Length > 2 && !TextColor[2].Equals(Color.Transparent))
                    list[2].ForeColor = TextColor[2];

                if (list[3] != null && TextColor.Length > 3 && !TextColor[3].Equals(Color.Transparent))
                    list[3].ForeColor = TextColor[3];

                if (list[4] != null && TextColor.Length > 4 && !TextColor[4].Equals(Color.Transparent))
                    list[4].ForeColor = TextColor[4];
            }

            CheckTexts();
        }

        private void CheckTexts()
        {
            Label prev = null;
            foreach (Label l in this.list)
            {
                if (l != null)
                {
                    using (Graphics g = l.CreateGraphics())
                    {
                        SizeF sz = g.MeasureString(l.Text, l.Font);

                        int linesNeeded = (int)Math.Ceiling(sz.Width) / l.Width + 1;
                        l.Height = (int)Math.Ceiling(sz.Height * linesNeeded);

                        if (prev != null)
                            if (l.ClientRectangle.IntersectsWith(prev.ClientRectangle))
                                l.Location = new Point(l.Location.X, prev.Location.Y + prev.Height + _spacing);

                        prev = l;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void startFeed()
        {
            try
            {
                {
                    // Set movement variables 
                    timer1.Interval = 50;
                    jump = 1;
                    // Start Timer 
                    timer1.Start();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("NewsFeeder Error: " + err);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I just added my project to my SkyDrive maybe someone can download it and see what i mean ? Now the program i set it back to use its original settings so you can see how its working suppose to work. What i want to do is to use the lines in the variable readableRss that i marked not to use now so you can see how the program suppose to work.

https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=EB1C71C44C3976D5!826&authkey=!AIlQC0FN4Q89ZAE&ithint=file%2c.rar

The file name is RssNews.rar

EDIT**

This is what im trying now:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            const int maxLines = 5;

            string[] lines = Regex.Split(readableRss, "\r\n");
            this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed = new string[maxLines];
            SetupText(lines.Skip(Math.Max(0, collection.Count() - maxLines)).Take(maxLines).ToArray());

                this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed = new string[5];
                this.newsFeed1.TextColor = new Color[5];
                SetupText(new string[] { "Hello everyone this is the weather for today", "Text2", "hello world this is a test for long text what do you think", "Text 4 -> 4", "Text Nr. 5" });
                SetupColors(new Color[] { Color.Blue, Color.Lime, Color.Maroon, Color.FromArgb(255, 71, 71, 255), Color.BurlyWood });
                //set this Variable to the Height of the Control to display one label at a time
                this.newsFeed1.Spacing = this.newsFeed1.Height;
                this.newsFeed1.SetTexts();
                this.newsFeed1.startFeed();
        }
```

But im getting errors on the line:

```
lines.Skip(Math.Max(0, collection.Count() - maxLines))
```

Error   5   'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Skip' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Skip(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, int)' has some invalid arguments

Error   6   Argument 2: cannot convert from 'decimal' to 'int'

Error   4   The name 'collection' does not exist in the current context

EDIT**

Fixed the errors but now i dont see anything in the UserControl this is the code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            const int maxLines = 5;
            readableRss = RssReader.covertRss("http://rotter.net/rss/rotternews.xml");
            string[] lines = Regex.Split(readableRss, "\r\n");
            this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed = new string[maxLines];
            SetupText(lines.Skip(Math.Max(0, readableRss.Length - maxLines)).Take(maxLines).ToArray());

                this.newsFeed1.TextColor = new Color[5];
                SetupColors(new Color[] { Color.Blue, Color.Lime, Color.Maroon, Color.FromArgb(255, 71, 71, 255), Color.BurlyWood });
                //set this Variable to the Height of the Control to display one label at a time
                this.newsFeed1.Spacing = this.newsFeed1.Height;
                this.newsFeed1.SetTexts();
                this.newsFeed1.startFeed();
        }
```

EDIT**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            readableRss = RssReader.covertRss("http://rotter.net/rss/rotternews.xml");
            const int maxLines = 5;

            string[] lines = Regex.Split(readableRss, "\r\n")
                               .Where(str => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
                               .ToArray();
            this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed = new string[maxLines];
            SetupText(lines
                         .Skip(Math.Max(0, readableRss.Length - maxLines))
                         .Take(maxLines)
                         .ToArray());
```

Not working i dont see anything.

EDIT**

Form1 code now but still not working dont see anything:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections;

namespace RssNews
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string readableRss;
        string t = "";
        int counter;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }




        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            readableRss = RssReader.covertRss("http://rotter.net/rss/rotternews.xml");
            const int maxLines = 5;

            string[] lines = Regex.Split(readableRss, "\r\n")
                               .Where(str => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
                               .ToArray();
            this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed = new string[maxLines];
            SetupText(lines
                         .Skip(Math.Max(0, readableRss.Length - maxLines))
                         .Take(maxLines)
                         .ToArray());
            /*const int maxLines = 5;

            string[] lines = Regex.Split(readableRss, "\r\n");
            this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed = new string[maxLines];
            SetupText(lines.Skip(Math.Max(0, readableRss.Length - maxLines)).Take(maxLines).ToArray());*/

                this.newsFeed1.TextColor = new Color[5];
                SetupColors(new Color[] { Color.Blue, Color.Lime, Color.Maroon, Color.FromArgb(255, 71, 71, 255), Color.BurlyWood });
                //set this Variable to the Height of the Control to display one label at a time
                this.newsFeed1.Spacing = this.newsFeed1.Height;
                this.newsFeed1.SetTexts();
                this.newsFeed1.startFeed();
        }

        private void SetupColors(Color[] colors)
        {
              if (this.newsFeed1.TextColor.Length > 0 && colors.Length > 0)
                   this.newsFeed1.TextColor[0] = colors[0];
               if (this.newsFeed1.TextColor.Length > 1 && colors.Length > 1)
                   this.newsFeed1.TextColor[1] = colors[1];
               if (this.newsFeed1.TextColor.Length > 2 && colors.Length > 2)
                   this.newsFeed1.TextColor[2] = colors[2];
               if (this.newsFeed1.TextColor.Length > 3 && colors.Length > 3)
                   this.newsFeed1.TextColor[3] = colors[3];
               if (this.newsFeed1.TextColor.Length > 4 && colors.Length > 4)
                   this.newsFeed1.TextColor[4] = colors[4];
        }

        private void SetupText(string[] textToDisplay)
        {
             if (this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed.Length > 0 && textToDisplay.Length > 0)
                  this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed[0] = textToDisplay[0];
              if (this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed.Length > 1 && textToDisplay.Length > 1)
                  this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed[1] = textToDisplay[1];
              if (this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed.Length > 2 && textToDisplay.Length > 2)
                  this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed[2] = textToDisplay[2];
              if (this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed.Length > 3 && textToDisplay.Length > 3)
                  this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed[3] = textToDisplay[3];
              if (this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed.Length > 4 && textToDisplay.Length > 4)
                  this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed[4] = textToDisplay[4];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what do you want to see in the SetupText, if your lines, for example, contain 3 items: "1", "2", "3"?

Comment: you want to pass all lines values in the same time or `five by five` ?

Comment: Selman all in same time i set it to 5 since the colors set up also are set to 5 colors. I want that there will be one color for all the lines and show all the lines.

Comment: @user3200169 do you want to append `"hi"` beginning of all lines ?

Comment: Updated my code with the code in form1. See the method SetupText and SetupColors. They are limit to 5 items i think now. I want to add all the lines from lines to the UserControl using this methods.

Comment: Updated my code again added the UserControl code. My program take a text and add it to the UserControl and the text is moving from the bottom to the top like an advertise.  Instead putting something i write in the SetupText i want it to hold all the lines in the variable lines. And the SetupColors to have one color to all the text/lines. But now as my code is now i need to give 5 string to SetupText and 5 colors to SetupColors.

Comment: I just added my project to my SkyDrive maybe someone can download it and see what i mean ? Now the program i set it back to use its original settings so you can see how its working suppose to work. What i want to do is to use the lines in the variable readableRss that i marked not to use now so you can see how the program suppose to work. https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=EB1C71C44C3976D5!826&authkey=!AIlQC0FN4Q89ZAE&ithint=file%2c.rar

Comment: The file name is RssNews.rar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your control is able to show only 5 items at time thus it is completely unnecessary to loop throught all the array of items and passing them one by one (or 5 by 5). Also setting list[i] to "my" will overwrite all the array with "hi" in the end.

So I would use something like this:

```
const int maxLines = 5;

var lines = Regex.Split(readableRss, "\r\n")
                   .Where(str => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
                   .ToList();
this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed = new string[maxLines];
SetupText(lines
             .Skip(Math.Max(0, lines.Count() - maxLines))
             .Take(maxLines)
             .ToArray());
```

Comment: JleruOHeP i tried your code now but im getting some erros. Please look at my question i updated it now with your code and the errors im getting.

Comment: Updated my answer. I believe you are getting empty control because of empty data in your feed. So I`ve added Where clause for lines.

Comment: JleruOHeP edited my question again with the current code its not working. I dont see anything. I changed in your code on the first line from ToString(); to ToArray(); and also from collection.Count to readableRss.Length;  but still not working.

Comment: @user3200169 sorry - you should use lines.Count instead of readableRss.Length as your option uses all the length of available text, not the lines count. Also, make sure that your readableRss actually have any data - try to debug it!

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you're looking for String.Join.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Join(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hm... Can you explain the benefit of join by a relevant example?

Comment: I think Microsoft's done that well enough on their site, I don't need to improve on it.  RTFM.

Comment: I meant relevant example for this question

Comment: -1. A link to documentation is not an acceptable answer here. RTFM is also not acceptable, whether it's in an answer or a comment. Be polite.